Installer keeps disappearing on dual boot installation
When installing the latest download of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.1 on a machine that already has a Windows 10 installation, during filling in the installation wizard with the information, on the left suddenly mounted disks appear and the installer disappears. This makes it impossible to install Ubuntu 24.04.1.
The windows 10 installation is GPT, fast boot is disabled and UEFI enabled. Installing Ubuntu 22.04 works just fine but installing an older version and updating it to 24.04 is not my preferred way of installing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Have you looked at system logs for any clues on why the ubuntu-desktop-installer closed/crashed?  Did your install media checks complete successfully? or you have other issues?  What checks have you performed (ISO, media etc)? Did you look for any clues? or came here first?

What partitions are currently on drive? Best to use Windows tools to shrink the NTFS partition to make unallocated space for Ubuntu install. Fast startup in Windows which sets hibernation flag and prevents LInux NTFS driver from mounting the NTFS partition is different than UEFI fast boot. Make sure fast startup is off, Windows may turn it back on with updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
